# Lowering bg music while another track plays and returning it to the previous volume afterwards

Tags: javascript, audio

Basically i have a background track and a play and pause button for a voiceover, when you play the voiceover the background drops to 0.25 and when the voiceover stops it's supposed to go back up to 1.0. You can see below the code i use for it, it does drop the bg music volume but when the vo is ended the bg music stays at the lower level. Oh and if you're wondering the if statement in StopBG is the start of trying to make the bg music return to normal only if it's playing, there's an option to silence it altogether. The site is [here](http://thecycle.ie/test.php) for those who want to have a look.

```
    function PlayVO()   
        {
            document.getElementById("vostate").value = "0";
            var voAudio = document.getElementById("voiceover_audio");
            var bgAudio = document.getElementById("background_audio");
            bgAudio.volume = 0.25;
            voAudio.volume = 1.0;
            voAudio.play();
            if(voAudio.ended)
                {
                    bgAudio.volume = 1.0;
                }
        }

        function StopVO()
            {
                document.getElementById("vostate").value = "1";
                var voAudio = document.getElementById("voiceover_audio");
                voAudio.volume = 0.0;
                voAudio.pause();
                voAudio.currentTime = 0;
                if(voAudio.volume == 0.25)
                    {
                        bgAudio.volume = 1.0;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: You will want to store the current volume of `bgAudio` in a variable when the voiceover starts, and then use that value when the voiceover ends.  You will also probably want to set up a listener on the `ended` event of `voAudio`, then call your `StopVO` function when the event fires.

Comment: You are also setting the volume of the VO to 0.0 and then checking if it is 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
//global variable
var oldBGVolume, voAudio, bgAudio;

document.onload = function(){
    voAudio = document.getElementById("voiceover_audio");
    bgAudio = document.getElementById("background_audio");    

    voAudio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        StopVO();
    });
}

function PlayVO()   
{
    document.getElementById("vostate").value = "0";
    oldBGVolume = bgAudio.volume;
    bgAudio.volume = 0.25;

    //If volume does not default to 1.0 keep this. Otherwise it is unneeded.
    voAudio.volume = 1.0;
    voAudio.play();
}

function StopVO()
{
    document.getElementById("vostate").value = "1";

    voAudio.pause();
    voAudio.currentTime = 0;
    bgAudio.volume = oldBGVolume;
}
```

Let me go through the changes a little bit...  I am storing your background audio volume in the global variable oldBGVolume.  I added a function for document.onload to set up your `voAudio` and `bgAudio` variables, and an event listener for the `ended` event.  The `StopVO` function is called once playback ends.
Finally, in your `StopVO` function, I restore the previous volume of the background audio.